# Log4j2 not logging Faces exceptions throught appenders

Tags: log4j2, java-ee-7, myfaces

I have a tomcat server with different applications and each one has it's own log4j2 appender which logs to it's own file, each java class logs it's exceptions properly, and for the JSF exceptions such as unclosed tags, wrong class/method/property name I made a defaultexceptionhandler which logs the FacesExceptions, but for some reason I can't find it doesn't log at all.

Here are the specs of the enviroment
Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04 (tried it on both just in case)
tomcat 8.0.47
oracle jdk 1.8.0_181
myfaces 2.3.1
log4j2 2.11.0

So the thing is that even while debugging the handle() while forcing exceptions by leaving tags open and so on, it does reach the breakpoints on the logger.error() call, but it just doesn't append to the file.

This is the declaration of the handler in the faces-config.xml of the project (I spared all the navigation cases and other junk, all of which works so far, I'll edit it all in if needed)

```
    <faces-config version="2.0"
                      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

        <factory>
            <exception-handler-factory>
                gescoweb.tools.DefaultExceptionHandlerFactory
            </exception-handler-factory>
        </factory>       

    </faces-config>
```

This is the DefaultExceptionHandler.java

```
package gescoweb.tools;

import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.faces.FacesException;
import javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandler;
import javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ExceptionQueuedEvent;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

/**
 *
 */
public class DefaultExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerWrapper {

    private ExceptionHandler wrapped;

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("gescoweb");

    public DefaultExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getWrapped() {
        return this.wrapped;
    }

    /** Recibe la lista de excepciones y las procesa según su tipo.
     * @throws FacesException 
     */
    @Override
    public void handle() throws FacesException {
        for (Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> i = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Throwable t = i.next().getContext().getException();
            if (t != null) {
                LOGGER.error("Error inesperado.", new Exception(t));
            } else {
                LOGGER.error("", new Exception(t));
            }
        }
        getWrapped().handle();
    }

    /**
     * Tratamiento especial de otras excepciones.
     * @param facesContext
     * @param t
     * @return 
     */
    protected String handleUnexpected(FacesContext facesContext, final Throwable t) {
        if (t instanceof IllegalStateException) {
            return "key.exception.IllegalStateException";
        } else {
            super.handle();
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the handler factory

```
package gescoweb.tools;

import javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandler;
import javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory;

/**
 *
 */
public class DefaultExceptionHandlerFactory extends ExceptionHandlerFactory {

    private ExceptionHandlerFactory parent;

    public DefaultExceptionHandlerFactory(ExceptionHandlerFactory parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    /**
     * Crea los handlers modificados.
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {
        ExceptionHandler eh = parent.getExceptionHandler();
        eh = new DefaultExceptionHandler(eh);
        return eh;

    }
}
```

And finally this is the log4j2.xml config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">${sys:catalina.base}/logs</Property>
        <Property name="layout"> [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} - %msg%ex%n </Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <!-- console appender -->
        <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}"/>
        </Console>

        <!-- logger gescoweb -->
        <RollingFile name="gescoweb-log" fileName="${log-path}/gescoweb.log"
                     filePattern="${log-path}/gescoweb/$${date:yyyy-MM}/gescoweb-%d{dd}.log.gz">
            <!-- log pattern -->
            <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}"/>
            <!-- set file size policy -->
            <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 12 */7 * ?"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <!-- logger catalina -->
        <RollingFile name="catalina-log"
                     fileName="${log-path}/catalina.out"
                     filePattern="${log-path}/catalina/$${date:yyyy-MM}/catalina-%d{dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}"/>
            <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 12 */7 * ?"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <!-- logger localhost -->
        <RollingFile name="localhost-log"
                     fileName="${log-path}/localhost.log"
                     filePattern="${log-path}/localhost/$${date:yyyy-MM}/localhost-%d{dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}"/>
            <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 12 */7 * ?"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <!-- logger manager -->
        <RollingFile name="manager-log"
                     fileName="${log-path}/manager.log"
                     filePattern="${log-path}/manager/$${date:yyyy-MM}/manager-%d{dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}"/>
            <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 12 */7 * ?"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <!-- logger host-manager -->
        <RollingFile name="host-manager-log"
                     fileName="${log-path}/host-manager.log"
                     filePattern="${log-path}/host-manager/$${date:yyyy-MM}/host-manager-%d{dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${layout}"/>
            <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 12 */7 * ?"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>

        <Logger name="gescoweb" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="gescoweb-log"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]"
                level="info"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="localhost-log"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager]"
                level="info"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="manager-log"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager]"
                level="info"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="host-manager-log"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="console-log"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="catalina-log"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind it, I imported the wrong log4j libraries in the DefaultExceptionHandler, changed the imports to

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

And everything works now...